# PouchDB find in array

Tags: angular, pouchdb

I have the following document (one) inserted into PouchDB:

```
{ 
 "_id": "5eaa6d20-2019-44e9-8aba-88cfaf8e02542",
 "data" = [
  {
    "desc": "VERSION",
    "id": 1452,
    "value": "32"
  },
  {
    "desc": "FIRM",
    "id": 1453,
    "value": "3232"
  },
  {
    "desc": "NONVERSION",
    "id": 1454,
    "value": "32213"
  },
  {
    "desc": "VERSION",
    "id": 1455,
    "value": "32_1"
  },
  {
    "desc": "VER",
    "id": 1456,
    "value": "32_3"
  }
]}
```

What I am looking for is an option to get JSON objects that have a desc = "VER" or starting with "VER". What's the best way to achieve this?

I have tried the following code:

```
this.db.find({
    "selector" : {
      "data" : {
        "$elemMatch" : {
          "desc": { $eq: 'VER'},
        }
      }
    },
    fields: ['desc', 'value'],
}).then((result) =>  {
  console.log('RESULT: ' + result);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log('Error while searching', error)
});
```

Any hints why this doesn't return any results?

Regards!

Comment: Can you reformat the JSON document? This is not valid JSON and my confuse people.

Comment: OK, this seems to work in the way that it returns the full doc instead of individual objects that contain the search element. Any ideas how to return internal objects that are there?

Comment: I think that you'll need to split them on client side.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved this by using the standard index/query solution that I have detailed here:

[PouchDB emit object from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636085/pouchdb-emit-object-from-an-array-of-objects)

Regards!